# Error: Incorrect syntax near '14'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have to insert values in the table using insert query...the table stored in the database has 3 columns: 1. Date (DateTime) 2. SensorValue (Float) 3. Difference (Float)
Now the values for each column comes from datagridview.....here is the button's code for inserting

```
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\dbsave.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    con.Open();
}
for (Int32 i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
{
    String query1 = 
        "INSERT INTO " + tbName + 
        " ( Date, SensorValue, Difference) " + "VALUES (" +     
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "," + 
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "," + 
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + ")";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("The table has been saved");
```

The error is ofcourse in execution of the query....the first entry in the date column is the value: 12/05/2012 14:32:00....so basically the sql is not accepting the colon that is placed with 14....how can i solve this problem ? please help

Comment: Please go and research parameterized queries - they avoid the issues with converting everything into strings.

Comment: What are the data types of those columns?

Comment: Please use DBParameter! It will make your query string more readable and it will help you to avoid MANY errors!

Comment: i have mentioned the datatypes.....Date is datetime, SensorValue is Float, Difference is Float

Answer (score 5, accepted):

update your query and add apostrophes:

```
String query1 = 
    "INSERT INTO " + tbName + 
    " ( Date, SensorValue, Difference) " + "VALUES ('" +     
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "'," + 
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "," + 
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + ")";
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
```

But I agree with Liath, parameters are more safe.

Comment: next time i will use parameters ;)

Answer (score 2):

That code doesn't even compile, so it can't give a runtime error.

You have a quotation mark too much here:

```
String query1 = "INSERT INTO " + tbName + " (" Date, Sensor...
```

Should be:

```
String query1 = "INSERT INTO " + tbName + " ( Date, Sensor...
```

When you have a datetime value, you need apostrophes around it:

```
...LUES (" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "," + ...
```

should be:

```
...LUES ('" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "'," + ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using parameterized queries. Like so:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO table (Date, SensorValue, Differences) VALUES (@Date, @SensorValue, @Differences)";            
var command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SensorValue", System.Data.SqlDbType.Float));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Differences", System.Data.SqlDbType.Float));
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
{
    command.Parameters["@Date"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
    command.Parameters["@SensorValue"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
    command.Parameters["@Differences"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: +1 for parameters, but please dont clear and re-add in the loop, but add outside of the loop and then only assign vales to the (then!) existing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all the variables it's difficult to diagnose although I'd SERIOUSLY recommend using parameters.  Not only will it make this sort of problem easier to spot but it'll protect you against sql injection attacks.